# Sharepoint with WCF Service HTTP request

Tags: rest, wcf, web, json, https

I have a Sharepoint solution with a WCF Service and a simple get method that returns a "Hello world". When making the request however, it doesn't return anything and I don't get any error either.

Any idea what could be causing this?

I am making the request in this form:
http://myServer/_vti_bin/Service1.svc/helloworld

This is my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

<appSettings>
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
<serviceBehaviors>
<behavior>
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
</behavior>
<behavior name="Service1ServiceBehavior">
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
</behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
<endpointBehaviors>
<behavior name="jsonBehavior">
<webHttp />
</behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
<service name="BAServiceMap.Service1"  behaviorConfiguration="Service1ServiceBehavior">
<endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior" contract="BAServiceMap.IService1" />
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
</service>
</services>
<!--<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>-->    
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
<directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: do you see the wsdl when you enter that url of the webservice in the browser?

Comment: yes, I see the wsdl

Comment: Have a look at the article in my answer

Comment: I created a new service using the MultipleBaseAddressWebServiceHostFactory and it works fine. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are on `SharePoint 2013`- I had to create a custom WCF service as well and there is good guidance for doing that in this [article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24194.sharepoint-2013-create-a-custom-wcf-rest-service-hosted-in-sharepoint-and-deployed-in-a-wsp.aspx)

You will not need to rely on a web.config file for your service because in your `.svc` file the use of the SharePoint-specific `MultipleBaseAddressWebServiceHostFactory` replaces the need to specify endpoint configurations in a web.config.

For Example your `.svc` will look like this:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true"
    Service="Barkes.Services.Presidents.PresidentsService, $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$"
    CodeBehind="PresidentsService.svc.cs"
    Factory="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Services.MultipleBaseAddressWebServiceHostFactory,
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
    PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```